# In a foreach loop, how do I target the last item in the loop?

Tags: loop, php

I have the following code to do a foreach loop, I want to target the last item in the loop (e.g if it's looped over 3 events I want to target the 3rd event) to do something slightly different with the css. How would I do that?

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
    foreach($pages as $post)
    {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $fields = get_fields();
?>
<div class="event">
    <img class="event-thumbimage" src="<?php echo $fields->thumb_image; ?>" height="120" width="140" alt="<?php echo $fields->event_title; ?>" />
    <h2><?php echo $fields->event_title; ?></h2>
    <p>
        Location: <?php echo $fields->location; ?><br />
        Start: <?php echo $fields->start_date; ?> at <?php echo $fields->start_time; ?>
        <?php $fields = get_acf(); if($fields->end_date != "") : ?>
        , End: <?php echo $fields->end_date; ?> at <?php echo $fields->end_time; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>                        
    <p style="margin-bottom:0px!IMPORTANT;"><?php echo substr($fields->description,0,170) . "..."; ?></p>
    <p><a class="read-more" href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID); ?>" title="Read more about: <?php echo $fields->event_title; ?>">Read more...</a></p>
</div>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this :

```
foreach( $pages as $key => $post )
```

and :

```
<div class = "event <?php if( $key == ( count( $pages ) - 1 ) ) echo 'last'; ?>" >
```

It will add a `last` class to your last `event` div.

Comment: Thanks, oddly it's added the last class to the 2nd item rather the 3rd one (i.e the last item).

Comment: Ah yes, that's because $key starts at zero, not one. I fixed the code. Tell me if it works now.

Comment: should be `if( $key == (count( $pages ) -1) )` since the array's first index is 0 while count functions starts from 1.

Comment: @Bainternet Thanks, knew what to do but couldn't get the syntax right!

Comment: @Bainternet It's acting a little strange. Using -1 as the count it makes the first item "last". When changing it to +1, it doesn't work when there's only two items in the list but works when there's 3, argh!!

Comment: @mike23 See comment above for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$pages` is an array, get its count by `$pages_count = count( $pages );` and then inside loop, keep a counter which is incremented at every iteration of the loop and compare if it equals the count `if ( $pages_count == $counter++ )`

Comment: Thanks, not quite sure how to implement that. The items are unlimited so it's not necessarily the 3rd item, just the last item.